# ggplot figure changes when adding a second axis (sec.axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to create a plot with two y axis, each of different values.
The moment I add the data of the second axis, the first axis gets extra (unwanted) area.
Any idea how to fix this?
I created some simple example, just to show what I do wrong.

Thank you!

```
    library(tidyverse)
starwars <- starwars[,c(2,3,7)] %>% drop_na() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(mass > 40 & mass < 200) %>%
  mutate(some_y = height/max(height))

viz <- starwars %>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = birth_year, y = mass), colour = "blue") + 
  labs(ylim = c(70,150))  #until here, the plot is fine

viz +
  geom_line(data = starwars,   #starting from here, it jumps up
            aes(x = birth_year, y = some_y*100), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name = "2nd y",
                labels = seq(0, 100, length.out = 11), breaks = seq(0, 100, length.out = 11)))
```

first, it works fine: (viz)

[image: viz]

Then, it jumps up: (viz + ...)

[image: see how left axis begins from 30]

Comment: In ggplot2 there is no "data of the second axis". All data is displayed on both axes. That's why the "axis jumps up". As the range of your red line data starts at around 30 the scale is adjusted accordingly when you add this line to your plot. If you want to have a second axis you (!!) have to transform your data. ggplot2 will not do that for you.

Comment: Thank you. Well, so I will just use the basic plot(). A bit ugly, but works well

Comment: The reason for this limitation is that plotting two variables that are not expressed using the same scale in the same panel is considered to be confusing and consequently it should be discouraged. The idea is that it is best to use separate panels or figures, one for each variable. On the other hand, in some fields like meteorology plotting multiple variables together using multiple unrelated axes is a frequently used practice.